# What is the maxium number of audio tags permitted on one page?

Tags: html, audio

Simple question, but I cannot find any documentation surrounding this.

With experimentation it seems to consistency stop showing the `HTML5 Audio Control` at exactly **60** in Firefox.

The source still indicates that the tag is available, and the `src` attribute correct, but no controls/track appear.

See image:

[image]

Comment: Can you check the css attributes, is it just invisible by default?

Also will javascript still let you play the audio despite it not being there?